# Regular Expression with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Im trying to create regular expression for preg_replace in php with

```
Input:    this us * action (if) * fsfsffs

Output: <b id="action"> * action (if) * </b>
```

So far I'm here,

```
$text = "    this us * action (if) * fsfsffs"
preg_replace( '#^(\s*)(\*)([^<>\n]+)(\*)(\s*)$#m', '$1<b id="$3">$2 $3 $4</b>$5', $text );
```

Output for same i get is,

```
<b id=" action (if) ">* action (if) *</b>
```

Comment: If you know exactly what you need to replace - don't use regex, use a simple substring/index replace.

Comment: Is this a fixed string?

Comment: No its not fixed. I need to use regex to match patters. Beside is it possible to make (if) param optional? this bracket part may or may not be in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
preg_replace('#\*\s+([a-z]+)\s+\(([a-z]+)\)\s+\*#', '<b id="$1">* $1 ($2) *</b>', $input);
```

Comment: what if we want to keep the (if) param optional?

Comment: `preg_replace('#\*\s+([a-z]+)(\s+\(([a-z]+)\))?\s+\*#', '<b id="$1">* $1$2 *</b>', $input);`